# Can seed show up in a place where similar seed already show up?

Tags: growtopia

In this movie, the guy eats blueberry and he has to move around. Why does he have to move around? Why can just he stay in one place and eat all the blueberry?

I tried putting 2 lava block and break them again and again. After long try seed does not drop in place where seed already there.

I tried putting 2 stone block and break them again and again. Again, I got only 2 seeds. No matter how many blocks are there.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just a downvote without any explanation whatsoever why the question is bad?

Comment: sadly that's kinda standard and sometimes things get mass downvoted and even when people ask there is no explanation. It is of course best to explain why you downvoted something unless it is obviously spam/insulting. I wish people would stop doing that!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is an answer  yet.

But this guy says the same thing

https://www.growtopiagame.com/forums/showthread.php?58897-Is-there-a-proper-way-to-get-blueberry-seeds

I think I know why.

You know how, if you break a block with an item or a gem in it already, you can only get another gem, and not a seed/block?
I know, I know, but they got it back, they removed the seed stacking thing.

> Anyway, so, when you use a Blueberry on yourself, it can drop a gem,
>   seed or a blueberry. When it does, it usually takes like 0.5-1 second
>   to take it. So if you're standing on the same place, not moving, most
>   of the blueberries will drop gems because of gems/seeds/blocks already
>   being on the same spot (because it takes time for you to pick it up).
>
> So, when using consumables, you should either stand on one spot and
>   wait until you pick up whatever is on the ground, or run and use.
>
> Again, this is what I THINK, it may or may not be true.

So I am not the only one with this problem.

I still have problems producing blueberry seeds even after I move a lot though.